# Need help locating mouse over color change in control template

Tags: wpf, combobox, mouseover, tabcontrol

My WPF application runs in cop cars and has a night mode which switches the application to more subdued colors so the screen won't affect the officer's night vision.  I've got almost all of the colors changed that I need to change.  The problem is the color of the background on mouse overs of the `Tab` control and the `ComboBox` control.  These turn to a bright blueish white color.

For the life of me, I can't find where this color change is happening.  The control templates for these controls do not contain a `Trigger` on the `IsMouseOver` property that I can find.

Does anyone know where I can find this setting?  Or should I just add an `IsMouseOver` trigger in my own custom templates that were based on the Aero templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Visual Studio 2012 and Windows 8 so my style might be a little different than yours.

```
<Style x:Key="TabItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFACACAC"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,2"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Border x:Name="mainBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0">
                            <Border x:Name="innerBorder" BorderBrush="#FFACACAC" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Background="White" Margin="-1" Opacity="0"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Left"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Bottom"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Right"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Left"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FFF0F0F0"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FFD9D9D9"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Bottom"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FFF0F0F0"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FFD9D9D9"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Right"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FFF0F0F0"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FFD9D9D9"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FFF0F0F0"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FFD9D9D9"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Left"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Left"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,0,-2"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Bottom"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Bottom"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,0,-2,-2"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Right"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Right"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-2,-2,-2"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-2,0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

So what causes the blue-ish color when you hover over it?
This little multitrigger right here:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

As you can see from the Conditions, it triggers when the mouse is over, and the tab strip is on top. There are a few other triggers looking pretty much the same, but for when the tab is on the right, left and bottom. Still, that's your color change.

Edit:
Here is the multitrigger for the ComboBox:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Comment: where did you get that XAML from?

Comment: In VS2012 (or Blend), if you right click a component you can select Edit Template -> Edit a copy.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look for the style for the `TabItem` class and see if I can find that multitrigger.  I have the same problem for the `ComboBox` class, though.  Any idea where the trigger is for that one?

Comment: @AkselK:  Thanks to your answer, I was able to fix the problem with the `TabControl`.  I still have the problem with the `ComboBox` controls, though.  I can't find any `IsMouseOver` triggers in the template that I have.  I'm going to try to blow away what I have and regenerate the template using Blend and see what happens.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, where did you get your templates from? Also, yes, I found the multitrigger in the combobox too. I can update the answer when I go to work tomorrow.

Comment: I downloaded the default WPF templates from Microsoft's site.  I don't remember the exact URL.  The template I have for the Aero theme is called Aero.NormalColor.xaml.  I can't find any trigger in there for the IsMouseOver.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @AkselK: Where's that trigger for the `ComboBox` class again?

Comment: I'm so sorry; Christmas got in the way and I forgot all about your question. But I edited it in now.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the the SystemColors, you can override these, I had similar issues with Buttons a while back (cant find the project :()

To overide the system burshes you can add lines like below to your `<Window.Resources>` or `<ControlTemplate.Resources>`

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HotTrackBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
```

Full list of the sustem colors to override can be found here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference.aspx

Like I said I'm not sure if this will help, but worth a shot :)